# How to draw vertical line in precise position

Tags: line

Please help: I want to draw 2 vertical lines:
one line at 148 cm & one line at 160 cm

```
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,left=0.5cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
```

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,left=0.5cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc,positioning,arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}





\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[,dash pattern=on 10pt off 3pt,line width=2pt]($(current page.north)+(0cm,-2cm)$)--($(current page.south)+(0cm,2cm)$);
\draw[line width=2pt,purple,latex-latex,,dash pattern=on 10pt off 3pt]($(current page.north west)+(0cm,-4cm)$)--($(current page.north)+(0cm,-4cm)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please consider restricting yourself to the necessary packages and libraries, in particular in answers. I do not see why `shapes`, `positioning` and/or `arrows` are needed, and anyway `arrows` got superseded by `arrows.meta`. Note that I do appreciate your efforts of helping here and do not want to criticize you, but please understand that it is not helpful to load unnecessary things. (BTW, with the `tikzpagenodes` package you may be able to achieve this in a slightly more elegant way.)

Comment: @F.HA: you're right. and where in your code that i can see "148 cm". I need draw other parallel line at 160 cm. Thanks

Comment: I didn't understand what you want, try this :

Comment: \foreach \x in {0,3,6,9,12,15,18}
\draw[,dash pattern=on 10pt off 3pt,line width=2pt]($(current page.north)+(\x cm,-2cm)$)--($(current page.south)+(\x cm,2cm)$);

Comment: Add after the second line : \draw .... node[rectangle,fill=green, below=1ex,pos=0.5]{148 cm}

Answer (score 1):

The following code uses [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) for exact positioning of two rules, one at `148mm` and another at `160mm` (`cm` lengths would not fit on the page since a `landscape` A4 is `297mm` wide). The rules are placed in the `F`ore`G`round of the page that it's called on (because of the `*`; removal of the `*` will place it on all pages).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  paper = a4paper,
  landscape,
  margin = 1cm,
  left = 5mm
]{geometry}

\usepackage{eso-pic}

\begin{document}

\mbox{}% Some text on this page
\pagestyle{empty}% Remove header/footer

\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \hspace*{148mm}%
    \rule{1pt}{\paperheight}%
  }%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \hspace*{160mm}%
    \rule{1pt}{\paperheight}%
  }%
}

\end{document}
```